# C# encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, encryption

I am trying to create a simple system that encrypts strings, converts the encrypted byte array to a string and stores it in the database. Later on, the values can be retrieved from the database (as strings), comverted to byte arrays, decrypted and then converted to strings again. I am also using a 256 bit key. However, I seem to be doing something wrong and I am not familiar enough with the concept to come up with a fix.

Encryption code:

```
private static string EncryptString(SymmetricAlgorithm symAlg, string inString)
{
    byte[] inBlock = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inString);
    ICryptoTransform xfrm = symAlg.CreateEncryptor();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(xfrm.TransformFinalBlock(inBlock, 0, inBlock.Length));
}
```

Decryption code:

```
private static byte[] DecryptString(SymmetricAlgorithm symAlg, string inBytes)
{
    ICryptoTransform xfrm = symAlg.CreateDecryptor();
    return xfrm.TransformFinalBlock(Convert.FromBase64String(inBytes), 0, inBytes.Length);
}
```

The error I am getting when decrypting:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Attempt to transform beyond end of buffer.
>   Parameter name: inputCount
>   at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
>   at
>   CDMEncryptionLibrary.SyncEncryption.SecureCDM.DecryptString(SymmetricAlgorithm symAlg, String inBytes)

I understand that the problem is the conversion from and to bytes but how can I solve it?

--Edit

Decryption code is now:

```
    private static string DecryptString(SymmetricAlgorithm symAlg, string inBytesString)
    {

        var inBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inBytesString);
        ICryptoTransform xfrm = symAlg.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] outBlock= xfrm.TransformFinalBlock(inBytes, 0, inBytes.Length);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outBlock);
    }
```

with error The input data is not a complete block.

Comment: @mjwills decryption. Will update the post. thanks

Comment: From where did you get the idea to call `TransformFinalBlock` before writing anything at all?

Comment: I guess the size of `inBytes` is not the same as the result of `Convert.FromBase64String(inBytes)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symmetric encrypt/decrypt in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150703/symmetric-encrypt-decrypt-in-net)

Comment: Hint: naming a *string* parameter `inBytes` is causing you confusion. I'd suggest naming it something more textual, and if you *want* an `inBytes` variable, that would be `byte[] inBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedBase64);` or similar.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09d0kyb3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Don't do `inBytes.Length` when decrypting. That's length of base64 encoded string in characters. You need `var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inBytes); xfrm.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the length of the **String**, not the length of the **byte array** you convert the String to.

I.e. You pass Convert.FromBase64String(inBytes) as the first parameter but inBytes.Length as the last. Simply convert before taking the length;

```
private static byte[] DecryptString(SymmetricAlgorithm symAlg, string inBytes)
{
    ICryptoTransform xfrm = symAlg.CreateDecryptor();
    return xfrm.TransformFinalBlock(Convert.FromBase64String(inBytes), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(inBytes).Length);
}
```

or to be more readable;

```
private static byte[] DecryptString(SymmetricAlgorithm symAlg, string inBytesString)
{
    var inBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inBytesString);
    ICryptoTransform xfrm = symAlg.CreateDecryptor();
    return xfrm.TransformFinalBlock(inBytes, 0, inBytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: The input data is not a complete block after changed the Padding to none

Comment: @MonicaS another error is another question. And for that new question it's better to post complete example (which string you encrypt exactly, what `SymmetricAlgorithm` you pass with which parameters, and so on).

Comment: You should set the padding, as having padding as None means you need to manually pad... Some Algorithms are 'block' cyphers so need a block of a certain size... padding adjusts your input to be that size. Note: Padding must match on encryption and decrption

Comment: I believe the recommended padding is System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7

Comment: @Milney whenever I change the padding to anything else than none I get the "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" error.

Comment: @MonicaS Are you sure you are setting the same padding in the encrypt function as you use in decrypt? That would imply that you have not correctly padded the encrypted input so when trying to decrypt it cannot remove it

Comment: Are you sure the keys are the same for encryption and decryption as this can also cause this error

Comment: Yes. I'm using the same Aes object with the same properties for both encryption and decryption.